# Transpose rows into columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have the output like below after parsing XML

```
Name        Type        Value 
doccreated  datetime    2017-05-05
docmodified datetime    2017-05-06
version     varchar(10) 3.1.42  
doccreated  datetime    2017-04-11
docmodified datetime    2017-04-12
version     varchar(10) 3.1.43
```

I need the output like below.

```
doccreated  docmodified version
2017-05-05  2017-05-06  3.1.42  
2017-04-11  2017-04-12  3.1.43
```

Comment: is there no column identifier that links the sets of three rows together?

Comment: Unsure how anyone is expected to help given you've provided no example XML files etc.

Comment: Please give a sample of your Data before parsing

Comment: No I dont have a column identifier

Comment: <root>
 <records>
  <record>
  <field name="doccreated" type="DateTime">2002-09-28T18:17:32.12Z</field>
  <field name="docmodified" type="DateTime">2002-11-19T15:18:26.19Z</field>
  <field name="Version" type="Double">0</field>
 </record>
 <record>
  <field name="doccreated" type="DateTime">2002-09-28T18:17:32.09Z</field>
  <field name="docmodified" type="DateTime">2002-12-13T15:53:50.66Z</field>
  <field name="Version" type="Double">0</field></record>
 </records>
</root>

Comment: I am a novice in xml... struggling to get the required format...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

**This**

```
DECLARE @yourXML XML =
'<root> <records> <record> <field name="doccreated" type="DateTime">2002-09-28T18:17:32.12Z</field> <field name="docmodified" type="DateTime">2002-11-19T15:18:26.19Z</field> <field name="Version" type="Double">3.1.43</field> </record> <record> <field name="doccreated" type="DateTime">2002-09-28T18:17:32.09Z</field> <field name="docmodified" type="DateTime">2002-12-13T15:53:50.66Z</field> <field name="Version" type="Double">3.1.43</field></record> </records> </root>'

SELECT 
  doccreated  = x.record.value('(field[@name="doccreated"]/text())[1]', 'date'),
  docmodified = x.record.value('(field[@name="docmodified"]/text())[1]', 'date'),
  [version]   = x.record.value('(field[@name="Version"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM @yourXML.nodes('/root/records/record') x(record);
```

**Results**

```
doccreated docmodified version
---------- ----------- ----------
2002-09-28 2002-11-19  3.1.43
2002-09-28 2002-12-13  3.1.43
```